# Html.BeginForm rendering with "/" action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following route defined

```
    routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I am then trying to use Html.BeginForm as below

```
     <% using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "login-form" }))
       { %>
```

But this renders me a form like below

```
    <form class="login-form" action="/" method="post">
    </form>
```

However if i change my defaults on me route to be something different like

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

My form then renders correctly, for info i am using `Html.BeginForm()` in a partial view that is returned from the login method on my account controller.

```
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {

       public ActionResult Login()
       {
           return View();
       }

       [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
       {
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
           {
              //TODO: Login user
            }
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is expected behaviour. Actually routing system is pretty clever and it knows the request which is coming that is for the default values.(In your case default controller is Account and default action is Login and in your begin form you are using the same controller and action). 
So routing system will replace it
    by '/'.

You can verify it by just adding one another controller let say Admin and the same View Login. And now just replace the controller by new controller like

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Admin", System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod.Post,
   new { @class =  "login-form" }))
```

Now you will have link like

```
<form class="login-form" action="/Admin" method="post"></form>
```

There will be no action, because routing system will find the action is default action.

Thanks

Comment: It on a partial view which is rendered from the login view of the account controller

Answer (score 0):

The behavior that you are noticing is expected and is also correct. When generating links MVC goes through the list of routes in the route collection(top-down) and sees which routes can match based on the route data that you are providing in Html.BeginForm. For example, you can imagine a request coming in like `POST /` and in this case your Account controller's Login action would be called because of the presence of defaults.

Comment: that is what i expected to happen, as im working on a hybrid of MVC and Webforms i found some legacy code that redirects to the old login web form if any request is trying to access application root. Many thanks